# Can a function exist whose first and second derivative are zero at a same point?

Tags: calculus, functions

Can we modify the RHS of a function $y(x)=J_m(kx)$, where J is a Bessel function of first kind, so that it will satisfy the Boundary Conditions $y'(a)=0$ and $y''(a)=0$?

But $y(a)\neq 0$ and $a> 0$.

Comment: What about $y(x) = 0$?

Comment: Can a function whose first and second derivatives are $0$ everywhere? **Edit:** OVERKILL - See the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: $x^n, n\ge 3 $ at x=0.

Comment: @tpb261 Shouldn't it be $n\ge3$?

Comment: @egreg yes, you are right. i somehow always feel "le=larger or equal". Corrected

Comment: I want these condition to be imposed on y(x)=besselj(n,k*x); and a=1; I'm unable to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The function $f(x)=(x-a)^3$ has the first derivative of $f'(x)=3(x-a)^2$ and the second derivative of $f''(x) = 6(x-a)$, meaning that $$f'(a) = 3(a-a)^2=0$$ and $$f''(a) = 6(a-a)=0.$$

In fact, take any function $f(x)$ such that $f'$ and $f''$ exist.

Then, define $$g(x) = f(x) + \left(af''(a) - f'(a)\right)x - \frac{x^2}{2}f''(a).$$

Then, $g'(x) = f'(x) + af''(a) - f'(a) - xf''(a)$ and $g''(x) = f''(x) - f''(a)$, meaning that $$g'(a) = f'(a) - f'(a) + af''(a) - af''(a) = 0$$
and $$g''(a) = f''(a) - f''(a) = 0.$$

This means that there are *a lot* of functions that satisfy $f'(a) = f''(a) = 0$, since you can construct one from any function you can think of (that has a second derivative at $a$).

Comment: Here $y(a)=0$. What if I need to force $y(a)\neq0$

Comment: Just replace it with $\bar y(x) = y(x) + 1$. Id does not affect the values of derivatives.

Comment: with ref. to your first comment, Did you mean to use instead of y(x), g(x)?.

Comment: This is great Sir.

Comment: Can you please tell me What is this theorem called??

Comment: What theorem? I didn't use any theorems in my answer...

Answer (score 3):

Of course! Why not? In fact

- $y'(a)=0$ means that the point $(a,f(a))$ is a stationary point
- $y''(a)=0$ means that in the point $(a,f(a))$ the function changes its concavity.
  A straight-forward example can be given by the function $f(x) = x^3$, in the point $(0,0)$:
- $y'(0)=3x^2=0$
- $y''(0)=6x=0$
  as you can see from the sketch below:
  [image]

Comment: "$y''(a) = 0$ means that in the point $(a,f(a))$ the function changes its concavity" is not necessarily true, in the same way that "$y'(a) = 0$ means that the function changes its monotonicity at $a$" isn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 1):

For any $g$ differentiable at $a$, take $y(x)=1+(x-a)^2g(x)$. Is sufficient $g$ continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Others already answered in detail, let me just demonstrate how easy it is to generate points with that property. Every differential function with zeros (pick any polynomial with real zeros) can be squared twice, and at the points of original zeroes, you get $y(a)=y'(a)=y''(a)=y'''(a)=0$. The first squaring makes the zero into a minimum/maximum (first derivative zero, parabolic $x^2$ behaviour around the zero), and the second squaring makes this $x^2$ behaviour into a $x^4$ behaviour.

Comment: What if $y(a)\neq 0 $?

Comment: This construction demonstrates these points happen at zeroes if you square the function twice. However, you can always move it down to zero at any point if you want: $(y(x)-y(a))^4$.